# how to convert mat file into xlsx file

Tags: excel, matlab

After executing code, I received an error:

```
 load('firstdiff.mat')
 xlswrite('test.xlsx', firstdiff)
```

mat file consist only numeric values (`0` and `1`)

> Undefined function or variable 'firstdiff'

Comment: What variable does `load('firstdiff.mat')` create in your workspace?

Comment: data=load('firstdiff.mat')

data = 

    ans: [403x19 logical]

Comment: So you load into a variable called `data` and then expect to use a variable called `firstdiff`??? Either `firstdiff-lod(...` or `xlswrite(..., data)`

Comment: after executing load('firstdiff.mat') i got a matrix of dimension (403*19) which consist only 0 and 1 values

Answer (score 1):

Using `load` without output arguments is something which often confuses programmers. I recommend to use it with an output argument:

```
data=load('firstdiff.mat')
```

This way you get a struct containing the data of your mat file. A typical next step would be using `fieldnames(data)` to check which variables are present or if you already know, index a variable with an expression like `data.x`

In this case I assume you only have one variable in your matfile.

```
data=load('firstdiff.mat');
fn=fieldnames(data); %get all variable names
assert(numel(fn)==1); %assert there is only one variable in your mat, otherwise raise error
firstdiff=data.(fn{1}); %get the first variable
xlswrite('test.xlsx', firstdiff); %write it
```